# Can I auto populate a cell in excel using information from multiple cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a form where sales people can enter information about a client ie: customer ID, rate card, product in 3 seperate cells and then for it to auto populate one cell in another sheet with all of this information.

Eg sales person enters in one worksheet (a form):

A1: product x
B1: customer 123
C1: rate card 1

And then in a separate sheet/workbook it would return results in one single cell based on this information to create a list of templates that need to be set up
This information would form the title of the template and can therefore easily be copy and paste in to our program

The title or return value it would display would be:

Product x - customer 123 - rate card 1

Not sure if this is possible!

There wouldn’t be a list to select from all input cells would be free text.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using a Form then you must be suing VBA (Macro),,, so better share the code with us for better understanding,,, to fix the issue!!

Comment: Did the return value generate automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the values of cells with `&` and reference other sheets just as you would reference other cells on the same sheet.

```
="Product "&Sheet1!A2&" - Customer"&Sheet1!B2&" - Rate Sheet"&Sheet1!C2
```

Note the hard-coded string values between cell references (e.g. " - Customer").  You can change these to adapt the formatting to your specific need, or whether the sales person will enter that text or just the values.

**Sheet 1**

```
A           B            C
Product     Customer     Rate Card
x           123          1
```

**Sheet 2**

```
A
Product x - Customer123 - Rate Sheet1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @NikiJones if this was helpful please accept the answer :)

Comment: Hi Scott. Actually I think I should have phrased my question better and now that I’ve gone and out it in a sheet I’m not sure the above works.

Comment: So I have 3 cells that a sales person needs to enter info to. One is position, one is client ID and one is rate card. I don’t want the words position client ID or rate card to appear in my answer but if the sales person enters labourer in position 123 in client ID and Account in rate card I would like it to return the following: labourer - 123 - Account is this possible?

Comment: So you want to just put whatever the sales person enters in 3 separate cells into one cell?  Try `=Sheet1!A2&" - "&Sheet1!B2&" - "&Sheet1!C2`

Comment: Yes that is correct combining 3 pieces of data in to one with the - in between. The above gave me the #VALUE! Error unfortunately.

Comment: Actually I have tried it again and it works! Thanks heaps

Comment: @NikiJones great! If this completely answered your question, please “accept” it :)